# Loading several C object files into GHCi

Tags: haskell, ghci

I have a Haskell project that contains almost a dozen C files that I access via FFI.  All documentation I've found suggest that in order to use GHCi while developing I have to invoke it with the C object files on the command line.  For a single object:

```
ghci dist/build/csrc/foo.o
```

or for all of them (since they all live in the same folder):

```
ghci dist/build/csrc/*.o
```

Is there no more convenient way of doing this, e.g. using `.ghci`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've no idea about a ghc-specific way of doing this. Write a short shell script?

Save this in a file called `repl` in the same directory as your .cabal file:

```
#!/bin/sh
ghci dist/build/csrc/*.o "$@"
```

Make it executable by running

```
chmod a+x repl
```

Then you can start ghci with all your C object files loaded by running

```
./repl
```

(These specific instructions assume you are using a Linux/BSD/Mac/Unix, but the same principle works if you are using Windows.)

Comment: Yes, that would be one way, and then I can skip using `.ghci` altogether since everything I can do in there can be done from the command line and hence in a script.